# Button isn't clicked (selenium c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Just trying below code to click Export button in and it not clicking the button

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and contains(.,'Export')]")).Click();
```

Outer HTML code

Export

```
<span class="ui-button-text" style="">Export</span>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Update the question with some more of the _outerHTML_

Comment: OK.. Just added more information about outerHTML

Comment: @Guy - I don't get any errors

Comment: show it parent html, it is button?

Comment: <a class="export ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="ui-button-text" style="">Export</span></a><div class="export-options" style="display: inline-block;">Excel</div>

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and contains(.,'Export')]")).click();
```

(lower-case `click()`).

Comment: it throws error in Visual Studio if I use lower case - "click"

Answer (score 0):

Resolved myself after digging into Wait methods. Below code recognizes the button.

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and contains(.,'Export')]"))).Click();